# ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.convert.AsJavaExtensions when using @EmbeddedKafka from spring-kafka-test

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

When trying to use `@EmbeddedKafka` from `spring-kafka-test`, I end up with `ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.convert.AsJavaExtensions` (full stack trace [here](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/73def25018e5201ef1cfc811dbd0dde2)) when running the test.

I've tried a different Kafka version (`org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.11:2.4.1` instead of `org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.12:2.8.0`) and also different versionf of `org.scala-lang:scala-library` (`2.13.6`, `2.12.10`, `2.11.12`, `2.10.6`).

What do I need to do in order to fix this?

Below is a minimal example to reproduce the problem:

### `src/main/kotlin/com/acme/Application.kt`

```
package com.acme

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication

@SpringBootApplication
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

### `src/test/kotlin/com/acme/integration/TestFullStack.kt`

```
package com.acme.integration

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafka
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@EmbeddedKafka(topics = ["testtopic"], controlledShutdown = true)
class TestFullStack {
    @Test
    fun `test init`() {
    }
}
```

### `build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.4"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.5.21"
}

group = "com.acme"
version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(group = "org.apache.kafka", name = "kafka_2.12", version = "2.8.0")
    implementation(group = "org.scala-lang", name = "scala-library", version = "2.12.10")
    implementation(group = "org.springframework.kafka", name = "spring-kafka", version = "2.7.6")
    implementation(group = "org.springframework.boot", name = "spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation(group = "org.jetbrains.kotlin", name = "kotlin-reflect")

    testImplementation(group = "org.springframework.boot", name = "spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation(group = "org.springframework.kafka", name = "spring-kafka-test", version = "2.7.6")
    testImplementation(group = "org.testcontainers", name = "kafka", version = "1.16.0")
    testImplementation(group = "org.jetbrains.kotlin", name = "kotlin-test-junit")
}

tasks {
    withType<Test> {
        testLogging.exceptionFormat = org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestExceptionFormat.FULL
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}
```

### `settings.gradle.kts`

```
rootProject.name = "acmetest"
```

### `Dockerfile`

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim
WORKDIR /home/test
ADD . /home/test
RUN ./gradlew test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it work by using the correct dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    implementation(group = "org.springframework.boot", name = "spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation(group = "org.apache.kafka", name = "kafka_2.13")
    implementation(group = "org.apache.kafka", name = "kafka-clients")

    testImplementation(group = "org.springframework.boot", name = "spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation(group = "org.jetbrains.kotlin", name = "kotlin-test-junit")
    testImplementation(group = "org.springframework.kafka", name = "spring-kafka-test")
}
```

Comment: An appendix in the reference manual explains that all the jars must be the same version: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#update-deps

Comment: @GaryRussell So I can just let Spring Boot’s dependency management choose the versions for me. I've tried, and it works nicely. Thanks! (I've adjusted my answer for future readers.)

Comment: Correct; you only need to specify versions (for all kafka-related jars) if you want to override Boot's default versions, and then, they must all be the same version.